# Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--configdb'

Tags: database, mongodb, configuration, nosql, sharding

I am following [this](https://coderwall.com/p/bzz1ra/set-up-mongodb-shard-windows-local) tutorial, that explains how to set up `mongodb shard` at `windows`. In step 3, it says to start a route process with the command

```
mongod --port 40000 --configdb localhost:27100 --logpath=/www/mongoDB/shard/log/route.log --chunkSize 500
```

and `windows console` returns:

> Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--configdb' try
>   'mongod --help' for more information

I tried `mongod --help` and I saw that `--configdb` really does not exist for `mongod`. How can I go through this step or solve this error?

I read [other](https://www.guru99.com/mongodb-sharding-implementation.html) tutorial, and in step 2 it uses the same `mongod` with `configdb`

```
mongod –configdb ServerD: 27019
```

I am using `MongoDB v3.4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this tutorial is for versions prior to 3.4. From 3.4 onwards the [config databases](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-config-servers/#sharded-cluster-config-server) are themselves a replica set (since it's very important that the data is not lost).

There's an [official tutorial for 3.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/) with more detail which works for the latest versions.

In summary, you're `--configdb` value will end up like `<configReplSetName>/cfg1.example.net:27019,cfg2.example.net:27019`

Answer (score 0):

You must use [`mongos`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongos/) instead of [`mongod`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/).

Official tutorial: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/